# add_action wp_ajax_ not loading in plugin file WP Network

Tags: plugin-development, multisite, ajax

I'm developing a plugin that relies pretty heavily on AJAX calls. It works well in a single-install version of WordPress, but when I ported it into a Network WP my AJAX functions stopped working (always return 0).

Simplified, my plugin setup looks like this:

```
// plugin.php
/*
Plugin Name: My plugin
*/
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) or die( 'No direct access.' );

add_action("wp_ajax_test_ajax", "test_ajax");
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_test_ajax", "test_ajax");
function test_ajax() {
    echo "Works";
    die();
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'cms_load_head_scripts2' );
function cms_load_head_scripts2() {
    $path = get_plugin_path();

    wp_enqueue_script('cmsAJAX', $path . 'js/script.js',
                        array('jquery'), '1.98' );
    wp_localize_script( 'cmsAJAX', 'myAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => get_admin_ajax_path()) );
}


// script.js
(function($) {
$(document).ready( function(){

    $.ajax({
        type        : "post",
        dataType    : "html",
        url         : myAjax.ajaxurl,
        data        : { 'action' : 'test_ajax' },
        success : function(response) {
            console.log( "success", response );
        },
        error   : function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        }
    });
```

The plugin otherwise works as expected; content loads, functions run etc. It's just the wp_ajax_ actions that don't run.

Through testing, I've determined **when I place my `add_actions('wp_ajax_` inside the theme's functions.php file, the calls work as expected** (even with the ajax call still in the plugin file). I do need them all to be in the plugin though.

I followed admin-ajax.php through and everything is functioning correctly up through the `do_action('wp_ajax_` call - no errors here, it just doesn't run my `test_ajax` action/function.

After writing this I've figured out that the AJAX calls works perfectly in the plugin **if the plugin is activated across the entire network**. It'd certainly be possible to only activate this plugin on on or two of the network sites individually though, so I'm still trying to figure out what's going wrong with these ajax calls in a single-site-of-a-network-site plugin.

**Also**

Here's the two custom `get_` functions I used above, they simply return the corresponding paths.

```
function get_plugin_path(){     return plugin_dir_url(__FILE__); }
function get_admin_ajax_path(){ return "http://domain.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php"; }
```

Comment: What is `get_admin_ajax_path()`? I've never seen that function before, it is written by you or it is from WordPress core? Can you post the code of that function?

Comment: Same for `get_plugin_path()`

Comment: Both of those functions are custom - they simply return the string path of the admin-ajax file and plugin directory. I had some challenges getting the ajax path to load right in multisite so just hardcoded as a temp solution, put it in a function so it's easy to fix in the future. I'm adding them to the original post.

Comment: Try to get the admin-ajax URL correctly. Instead of hard-coding it, you should use `admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )` in sigle site instalattions, `network_admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )` to get the ajax url of current site in multisite enviroment or [`get_admin_url()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_admin_url) function if you need to control exactly which site of the network should be used (not necessarily the current site).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `get_admin_ajax_path()` use `self_admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )` which retrieves the URL to the ajax address for either the current site or the network.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a multisite installation, better to use the inbuilt WordPress core function [network_admin_url](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/network_admin_url) to retrieve the admin-ajax.php url